# Divinity Original Sin EE - recenter camera on characters

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I turned on edge scrolling, which is great.  However, is there a way to quickly recenter the camera on my characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it should be the `home` key to center on everyone.

The `[ ]` keys should cycle through characters by default.